# Implementing ngOnChange to capture old and current value in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I was trying to implement ngOnChanges() to capture previous and current value. The function I have implemented works fine. I am able to see previous and current value in the console but I am getting this error even though my code is compiling successfully. I am getting the same error for "propertyName", "change", "current" and "previous". If I use 'const' instead of 'let' then my function doesn't work. Please help!!

[image]

Code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-simple',
templateUrl: './simple.component.html'
})
export class SimpleComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() simpleInput: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    for (let propertyName in changes) {
    let change = changes[propertyName];
    let current = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
    let previous = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
    console.log(propertyName + ' : currentvalue ' + current + ', previousvalue ' + previous);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you write the actual code it's hard to help you with a screen shot....

Comment: @MikeTung - I have added the code. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What do you mean your function doesn't work when you use `const`? What happens? What goes wrong?

Comment: @AamirKhan - My code fails to compile and the function doesn't execute if I use const. It's working fine as I have written above but I am getting this error as shown above which is confusing me.

Comment: It's a linter error, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ESlint error: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const

Your code **will** work fine, because there is nothing wrong with it programatically, it is just not good for readability as noted in the link I have provided. If you don't want to see the error, you can disable it in your tslint.json file. You can do this manually OR use the third option from the error dialog i.e. 'Remove rule `prefer-const` from tslint.json'.

Comment: Yes this worked!! I just set 'prefer-const' and 'forin' properties to false in tslint.json file. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to iterate array. Using **of** in advanced for loop.
Try using `for (let propertyName of  changes){}`
This might help you.

Edit1:
If a variable is never reassigned, using the const declaration is better.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const
Try like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
for (const propertyName in changes) {
  if (changes[propertyName]) {
    const change = changes[propertyName];
    const current = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
    const previous = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
    console.log(propertyName + ' : currentvalue ' + current + ', previousvalue ' + previous);
  }
```

}
  }

Comment: I tried the same but I am still getting the same error. Moreover, my code fails to compile if I use 'of' instead of 'in'.

Comment: Why you are using let change = changes[propertyName]; you can directly use  let current = JSON.stringify( propertyName.currentValue);

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: can you check this?